# Monospace icon font in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, font-awesome, monospace

I am inserting icons from FontAwesome and other icon fonts into Emacs but I would like to get them aligned with the monospace font I use (DejaVu Sans Mono). Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workable solution. I have installed a number of Nerd Fonts. These mostly solve the problem, but occasionally the alignment was still off by a few pixels. However, it seems that, when a glyph is available in multiple fonts, Emacs will try to match its width to that of the fixed width font in use. So, installing sufficiently many Nerd Fonts has solved the problem for me.